# Global Variable with ActiveX Control Elements

Tags: excel, vba

I am a bit lost with learning VBA currently and I don't know what topic to google.

In my Excel-Sheet, I have a Button and a ComboBox. By pressing the Button, I load some data into VBA. The title of certain data entries is added as Item into the ComboBox. The other data is added into a jagged array `s`.

Now, by changing the ComboBox-Selection, I want to access array `s`. How can I do this?

The code is in the sheet1/workbook control in the VBA Editor

```vb
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim s() As Variant

    Code Execution

    For i = 1 To m
        s(i) = SomeArray
    Next i

    For j = 1 To i - 1
        Sheets("Sheet1").ComboBox1.AddItem b(j)
    Next j
End Sub

Public Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Sheets("Steuerung").Cells(1, 1).Value = ComboBox1.ListIndex
    Sheets("Steuerung").Cells(2, 1).Value = UBound(s, ComboBox1.ListIndex + 1)
End Sub
```

The last line `UBound(s, ...)` results in an error, since the variable is unknown.

I don't know how to tackle this issue.

PS: Sorry, if I used wrong names but my Excel isn't the english one.

Comment: You need `s` to be declared in a higher scope, see *Module scope* - [Scope of variables in Visual Basic for Applications](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/141693/scope-of-variables-in-visual-basic-for-applications)

Comment: I tried ``Public s() As Variant`` in the first line before ``Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()``. But I can't compile it

Comment: Use `Private` not `Public` if the code is within a userform.

Comment: It is not part of a seperate userform but the button and combobox/dropdown are in the workbook in sheet1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do two things: declare the jagged array as `Public` at the module level and also be sure to initialize it.  For example, your module can look like this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Const MAX_ARRAYS As Long = 25
Public s As Variant      'my jagged array

Public Sub InitializeTheArray()
    '--- initializes the jagged array, only if necessary
    If Not IsArray(s) Then
        '--- perform initialization here...
        '    at least establish some dimensions
        ReDim s(1 To MAX_ARRAYS)
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    InitializeTheArray
    Code Execution
    For i = 1 To m
        s(i) = SomeArray
    Next i

    For j = 1 To i - 1
        Sheets("Sheet1").ComboBox1.AddItem b(j)
    Next j
End Sub

Public Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    InitializeTheArray
    Sheets("Steuerung").Cells(1, 1).Value = ComboBox1.ListIndex
    Sheets("Steuerung").Cells(2, 1).Value = UBound(s, ComboBox1.ListIndex + 1)
End Sub
```

Calling `InitializeTheArray` within each of your routines can guarantee that the public array is always initialized to some degree.